# Newtonsoft.Json serialize object will throw FileNotFoundException if the object contains customize attribute

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, custom-attributes

```
[CSVTable]
  public class Course {
    [CSVColumn("Course")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    [CSVColumn("Name")]
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    [CSVColumn("Date")]
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
  }

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Course() { CourseName = "Course", Teacher = "One", CreatedTime = DateTime.Now });
```

throw FileNotFoundException about dll
“System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a” not loaded
at method 'JsonConvert.SerializeObject'

about CSVTable and CSVColumn:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
  public class CSVColumnAttribute : Attribute, IComparable<CSVColumnAttribute> {
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; } = "default";
    public CSVColumnAttribute(string Header) { HeaderText = Header; }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] CSVColumnAttribute other) {
      return other == null ? 0 : Order.CompareTo(other.Order);
    }
  }
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
  public class CSVTableAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "default";
    public char JoinChar { get; set; } = ',';
  }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.  This appears to be a generic problem in that JsonConvert.SerializeObject is requiring another reference/package at runtime that you aren't providing.  As this is a project/solution config issue, please add details of framework versions etc.  If .NET core - this thread may help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

The Attributes defined in .net core project,and referent it in .net framework project.
Just define a new class for Newtonsoft.